# dropbox api exception android

Tags: android, dropbox-api

When i tried to download a file from dropbox using dropbox api in android then i got a exception something like this

```
DropboxException:DropboxServerException (nginx): 400 Bad Request ('rev' is not well-formed: "/storage/sdcard0/SMSbackUpTOSS/DropBox/allSMS_01-Sep-2015.txt")
```

I am getting exception in this line

```
fd = mApi.getFileStream(fileSelected.path,
                        localFile.getPath());
```

Because no other line under this works.

But the same code in another project works fine. I dont understand why i am getting this exception!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mApi.getFileStream(fileSelected.path, **localFile.getPath()**);

the second parameter here is rev, that is the revision of the file.

You should try to use `null` if you want the latest revision.

Comment: What is the difference?? could you explain it ? @Derek Fung

Comment: when you upload file, say **abc.txt** to Dropbox, you can actually keep uploading new **abc.txt**, and Dropbox will keep your all version of file as revisions. i.e. you can have 10 copy of **abc.txt** with different contents, and by specifying the **rev**, you can get back the old versions

Comment: If i use null then what will happen?

Comment: it gets the latest version